# PHP dropdown populated by database. Keep value after 'onchange' form submit

Tags: javascript, php

I have a drop down list that is populated by calling another PHP file who's values are taken from a database. The functionality works but I would like to retain the value selected once the onchange form submit happens.

I have had success by using the following for a static lists but not sure how I can get it to work for a dynamic list that is obtained from a database

```
<option value="company" <?php if($_GET['sort']== 'company') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Company</option>
```

Here is the HTML code for the select

```
<select name="client" id="client" onChange='this.form.submit()'>
    <option value="default"></option>   
<option value="all">----- ALL CLIENTS -----</option>    
<?php
  include("sql_clients.php");
?>
```

And here is part of the the sql_clients.php code

```
if (sqlsrv_has_rows($result)) {
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))     
    {   
        echo ('<option value="' .$row[CompanyName] . '">' . $row['CompanyName'] . "</option>" ."\n" ."\t" ."\t" ."\t" ."\t" ."\t");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the same thing, just now instead of one hardcoded value, use the variable:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))     
{   
   echo '<option value="' .$row['CompanyName'] . '"';
   if($_GET['sort']==$row['CompanyName']) 
   {
      echo ' selected="selected"';
   }
   echo '>' . $row['CompanyName'] . "</option>" ."\n" ."\t" ."\t" ."\t" ."\t" ."\t";
}
```

Also `$row[CompanyName]` should be `$row['CompanyName']`

Comment: Worked perfectly developerwjk. I was playing around with something similar yesterday but had the if statement in the wrong spot so all were getting the code selected="selected" applied. Thanks again, much appreciated.